# How does language [X] handle indeterminate forms like 0^0?

Tags: bug, math, language-features

As x goes to 0, the limits of x^0 and 0^x go to 1 and 0, respectively. Some say that the best value for 0^0 depends on context, others say that the value of 0^0 should be 1. I'm interested in knowing what your language implementers say. There doesn't seem to be a consensus. For example, in ActiveState Perl 5.12.0:

```
C:\>perl -e "print 0**0"
1
```

While in Mathematica 6.0:

```
In[1]:= 0^0
        During evaluation of In[1]:= Power::indet:
        Indeterminate expression 0^0 encountered. >>
Out[1]= Indeterminate
```

I'm also interested in knowing your opinion on the matter: What should 0^0 be? And also whether you have ever introduced a bug into a program you were writing (or had a hard time debugging a program) because of the way your language handles indeterminate forms?

Comment: What is the actual question? There is consensus as to what 0^0 means; [it's indeterminate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form#The_form_00). Languages that don't flag it as such are wrong. What's to discuss? It's no different than if a language returned anything other than undefined for 1/0.

Comment: @Mark: actually, for 1/0 it can return 'infinity', if it has such a thing available. A better example would be '0/0', which really is indeterminate.

Comment: Jerry: fair enough. I was thinking more of the "division by zero" assertion/exception/error most languages have that would produce an undefined value. Such behavior is more or less uncontroversial; 0^0  should be, too.

Comment: @Mark: I don't agree that there's a consensus. According to Donald Knuth, 0^0 "has to be 1." August Mobius agrees that its 1. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Zero_to_the_zero_power

Comment: @Mark: There are three related questions. Let me restate them succinctly: 1- Which languages implement 0^0=1 and which implement it as "Indeterminate" (or something else?) 2- Does it matter to you which way its implemented? 3- Has the way its implemented ever caused you practical issues?

Comment: @Elisha Abuyah - Personally, I prefer for the language to give out a very loud message on that. 0^0=1 can cause trouble in engineering fields, and it is rarely practically encountered. As for 1/0, it should certainly produce a runtime error, if the language has not got "Inf". Since one "Inf"/=another "Inf" this can produce serious problems. In general, I prefer very loud messages on all such corner cases. Provide a mechanism to deal with them, but do warn of them when encountered.

Comment: Some languages have inf and still give an exception when dividing by zero.

Comment: @A.N. Other: Consider code to evaluate a polynomial.  Like in Python, `sum(c * x**i for (i, c) in enumerate(coefs))`.  Without `0**0 == 1`, this doesn't work for `x == 0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Zero_to_the_zero_power) Wikipedia article,

"Most programming language with a power function are implemented using the IEEE pow function and therefore evaluate 0^0 as 1. The later C and C++ standards describe this as the normative behavior. The Java standard mandates this behavior. The .NET Framework method System.Math.Pow also treats 0^0 as 1."

Comment: Good insight. So clearly, Mathematica isn't IEEE-compliant, since it returns 0^0=Indeterminate rather than 0^0=1. Perhaps, then, the first part of my question should be rephrased as, "Which programming languages aren't IEEE-compliant, and return something other than 1 for 0^0?"

Answer (score 3):

Python:

```
>>> for t in [int, float, complex, fractions.Fraction, decimal.Decimal]:
...     print(t, t(0)**0)
... 
<type 'int'> 1
<type 'float'> 1.0
<type 'complex'> (1+0j)
<class 'fractions.Fraction'> 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
decimal.InvalidOperation: 0 ** 0
```

Comment: This is very, very interesting: So, in Python, the value of 0^0 depends on the numeric *type* of the base! Bravo and +1 for taking the trouble to find this out!!!

Comment: Elisha: well, it also depends on each type's intended purpose. Most of the above types follow the convention to return 1, as seems generally more convenient. The [`decimal`](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) module/type, on the other hand, is intended to be a standards-compliant implementation of the IBM/IEEE decimal floating point specifications, which might be more conservative about `0**0`. (I'm not sure, though.)

Answer (score 1):

Google says:

> 0^0 = 1

Answer (score 0):

Delphi's got 2 float values: `NaN` and `Infinity`. That get returned in case of weirdness.

But it doesn't have a built in exponentiation function.

`^` is for pointers, as in "hey you up there, I'm pointing at you!"

Comment: I always heard `^` pronounced "hat".

Comment: Makes more sense than carrot, or carat...

Comment: Standard Pascal has no exponentiation operator either. Timo Salmi contributed an exponentiation function to the Pascal FAQ here http://www.midnightbeach.com/jon/pubs/clp-faq.htm#exponentiation which looks as if it makes 0^0=1 rather than NaN. Do you agree with this implementation?